# Use local fonts with Gatsby 4 and Emotion

Tags: gatsby, styled-components, emotion

I'm trying to use a local font in Gatsby 4 and Emotion. Emotion is properly set up, as I'm using it for other styling already.

To achieve this, I've followed this guide: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/recipes/styling-css/#adding-a-local-font

So I've created the folder `src/fonts`, put my fonts there and defined them in the Emotion CSS:

```
export const defaultStyles = (theme: Theme) => css`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/pt-sans-v12-latin-ext_latin-regular.eot');
    src: local(''), url('../fonts/pt-sans-v12-latin-ext_latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/pt-sans-v12-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('../fonts/pt-sans-v12-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/pt-sans-v12-latin-ext_latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
  }
`;
```

In my layout component I'm declaring this as a global style:

```
<Global styles={defaultStyles} />
```

Unfortunately the fonts are not copied to the output of Gatsby upon `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` therefore the browser cannot find and display them.

How can I make Gatsby detecting the fonts within Emotion CSS and copy them?

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths or playing around with the relativity of the paths?

Comment: Yes I've tried all sorts of paths. Relative to the css file, relative to the projects root, absolute file system paths, .. nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it's been a while since you asked this, and I hope you figured it out. Since I landed here with the same problem and afterwards figured it out, here was what worked for me:

```
import myFont from "../fonts/my-font.woff2";

const Main = styled.main`
  @font-face {
    font-family: "My Font";
    src: url(${myFont});
  }

  font-family: "My Font", sans-serif;
`
```